# check if a link is clicked with certain attribute

Tags: jquery, css, list, click, anchor

How do I check if this particular link with the following href attrib is clicked? and then give a background color to its 'li' when clicked using jquery?

```
 <ul class="static">
    <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" href="/SitePages"> </a></li>
    <li>other anchor tags</li>
    <li></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: You first need to open the quotes you're closing at the end of the `href` attribute. Also, the `a` element doesn't *have* any `li` elements. So, what particular `li` elements are you wanting to change the background of, when clicking that `a`?

Comment: Instead of changing the background color on the `LI`, you should consider styling the `A` tag to cover the `LI`. Having done that, you can simply change the color on the `A` tag itself (and that can be done using CSS 2.1 selectors: `a[href='/SitePages']:focus { background: black; }`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$('a[href="/SitePages"]').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('li').css({
        backgroundColor: "#000"
    });
});
```

> [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wBJzh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery,

```
$('a[href="/SitePages"]').click(function(){this.parent.css("background-color", "blue")});
```

or if the parent isn't guaranteed to be a `li`, you can do this:

```
$('a[href="/SitePages"]').click(function(){this.closest('li').css("background-color", "blue")});
```